# Websocket Program in jquery Mobile in Ios show data

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is this possible to do websocket programming in jquery mobile.I am using jquery movile in IOS and android .I need to show data which is coming in port .I need to show data  my screen .Please tell me how to do websocket programming in websocket.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jquery mobile is just a user interface API basically. Yes you can easily implement web sockets using javascript. Jquery mobile has a lot of javascript APIs available as well to call after you recieve your websocket data.

Maybe jquery has a websocket implementation I am not sure, otherwise you will have to implement your own websocket components.

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-websocket/

http://api.jquerymobile.com/

Comment: How to build socket component? actually i am beginner that why i am asking?